# parse server file upload

Tags: curl, parse-server

I've created an instance of parse server.

I can get data from the collection no problem, but I'm stuck as to how to upload text files.

I'm running curl from windows to upload a simple backup log.

When I run:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: CITBackDash"
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: nottherealpassword" -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
  -T "C:\users\CITsmithy\Backup-Log.txt" http://1.1.1.1:1337/parse/1/files/backup-log.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":"Unexpected token E"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, for those idiots who get stuck like I did, the parse API mounting point for file uploads is... http://1.1.1.1:1337/parse/files/backup-log.txt

Not http://1.1.1.1:1337/parse/1/files/backup-log.txt

Bit silly of me.